# Based on Hours,how can i change the color of a date of calender in java?

Tags: java, android, date, colors, hour

Am Beginner to java.I have a small doubt while i am developing an application in android.Created a table for employee details with the table name empdet.In that table,the hours field must entered by the user itself.In a day there are 24 hrs.If an employee works for 8 hours,the day of a calender must show one color,if he works more than 8 hrs,the day of that calender must display another color.Like wise if he works for less than 8 hrs,it must display an another color.In my table empdet,with the reference of date value,am fetching the hours field.Based on those hours,when the application launches,the dates of a calender must seen with the colors of hours for knowing that for how many hours he worked based on the color.Please help me out of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calendar date is a specific type of widget, probably a TextView?
If so, you use TextView.setTextColor(int color).

If it ain't a TextView, you will have to reformulate your question.
Best regards.